# How to store an arborescent tree in array?

Tags: data-structures

I want to store a tree in an array, while being able to compute father and child index easily from the current index, like in a binary heap. The tree has a single root node, which is at level 0. The tree has N levels, each node at level i has n(i) children.

Can this be done? How?

EDIT:

Clarification: You can store a (complete) binary tree, i.e. to store a heap, in a single array without explicitly storing the indices. Root goes at 0, children of the node in position i go in 2i+1 and 2i+2. So you can *compute* the children from the index of the parent node, without actually needing to *store* the index. The data structure is *implicit* in the data, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Heap_implementation

My question: can you generalize this to a more general tree, as detailed above.

Comment: What you are looking for is likely related to succinct data structures, representations of data structures that use close to the information-theoretic minimum number of bits.  I don't know of any such representation, but I'm curious to find out if they exist.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you want to say ( each node at level i has n(i) children) then is very simple : The first number is the root fallowed by n(0) elements that are the root's children , then you put for all those n(0) nods all their n(1) nodes. 
If you have n(0) = 3 then for the first you put n(1) nods, after them you put all the n(1) nods if the second nod, and and after those the n(1) nods for the 3rd nod

```
1 -> 2, 5, 3 ( 1 is the root, and has 2, 5, 3 as children)
2 -> 4, 10
3 -> 45, 35
5-> 12, 31
n(0) = 3, n(1) = 2 , n(2) = 0
Then You should have: {1,  2, 5, 3,  4, 10,   45, 35,  12, 31}
```

For a good index you should keep another array with the father position and another with the first child index or if you realy want to have just one array you should do this:
    For each element keep 3 things: the father index and the first child index.
    Because the child are one after another you will allways have access to all the children
    and you will allways have the father. ( I will put -1 for the root's father)
Then you should have :

```
{1,-1, 3,   2, 0,12,   5, 0, x,    3, 0,  x,     4,  3,  x,  ... } 
{0, 1, 2,   3, 4, 5,   6, 7, 8,    9, 10, 11,    12, 13, 14, ... }
-1 is the father of 1 and 3 is the start of his child
0 is the father of 1 and 12 is the start of his child ( 4 in this case)
```

If you want a "heap" structure you have to find the largest number of children Mx = ( max(n(i)), 1<=i<=N and do a heap with step MX, each element will have their children at pos*MX, pos*MX + 1, ..pos*MX + n(k),   and the father at pos/MX, where the pos is the index of the node.

 You will have a lot of free spaces but is a heap-like stuture
I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks. Thing is, I would like to avoid "storing" the father and child indices, but rather compute them from the current index. Will edit question to clarify.

Comment: @willem see how if it's what you want( the last paragraph )